# Is the First Order attempting to finish the Empire's work or are they working towards a different goal?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Though it's implied that they are trying to complete what the Empire started, they also seem to run things differently and never truly state what it is they are attempting to accomplish. At first glance it seems as though they are going for good old fashioned galactic conquest, but I would think they would have learned their lesson from the Empire. Is anything else implied that I may have missed?

Comment: Check out the new canon book "Bloodline" - it has some good bits on the origin and motivations of the First Order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, they (nominally) want to resurrect the Empire

From *The Force Awakens* novelization, we see that according to Kylo Ren:

> "It is the task of the First Order to remove the disorder from our own
>   existence, so that civilization may be returned to the stability that
>   promotes progress. A stability that existed under the Empire, was
>   reduced to anarchy by the Rebellion, was inherited in turn by the
>   so-called Republic, and will be restored by us. Future historians will
>   look upon this as the time when a strong hand brought the rule of law
>   back to civilization."

That said, Supreme Leader Snoke may well have a different motivation.

Comment: It will all come down to Snoke's origins, imo

Comment: As I suspected it might. I was checking to see if I may have missed some minor detail or reference, as I've only seen the movie once (which is odd for a nerd such as myself). I suppose we will have to wait until episode VIII to see for certain.